# accessing location and activity from same api

Tags: android, google-api-client

```
val client = GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(Awareness.API)
                .build()
        client.connect()
```

I am learning google api's where I found Awareness API but when I am importing it in android studio, It displays deprecated. What is alternative way for accessing location and activity from same api.

Is it okay to go with Activity Recognition? and Fused Location?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: I am using both.. Activity recognition and location service. Currently I don't know about other solution so

Answer (score 0):

It's actually stated in the release notes of Google API Services 
 [release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

- Awareness

  - Updated the `Awareness` API for the new GoogleApi-based clients, which automatically manage connections to services and require less boilerplate code to use:

    - Added the `FenceClient` class and the `Awareness.getFenceClient()` methods. Use FenceClient instead of FenceApi.
    - Added the `SnapshotClient` class and the `Awareness.getSnapshotClient()` methods. Use `SnapshotClient` instead of `SnapshotApi`.

`FenceClient` has below method which is similar to the original API

```
public Task<Void> updateFences(FenceUpdateRequest var1) {
    return zzbj.zzb(Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(this.zzago(), var1));
}

public Task<FenceQueryResponse> queryFences(FenceQueryRequest var1) {
    return zzbj.zza(Awareness.FenceApi.queryFences(this.zzago(), var1), new FenceQueryResponse());
}
```

Comment: Is answer is related to quation?

Comment: Are you asking alternative because of Awareness API deprecation or just general location related, if it's just location then you can use normal location API, you don't have to use Awareness API. Awareness API is built more for GeoFencing.

Comment: do you want to use Awareness API or not? If yes then refer to my answer, otherwise there is no API to get both location and activity at the same time.